# Drupal 8 - How to edit a user as admin without changing the password

Tags: 8, users

Does anyone know how to edit user profiles as an administrator in Drupal 8(change roles in my case) without having to know or change the password?

Thanks

Comment: Its simple go to "`/admin/people`". Edit the user and change the role and save it.

Comment: I think password field is not mandatory. You remove the prefilled value and try to save the form.

Comment: If the password field is pre-filled, then that's because your browser or extension is trying to be intelligent and fills it out automatically. Try teaching it not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the command line using drush user-add-role.
To find the exact syntax, type :

drush help urol

Hope it helps.